# numpy array equivalent for += operator

Tags: python, numpy

I often do the following:

```
import numpy as np

def my_generator_fun():
    yield x # some magically generated x

A = []
for x in my_generator_fun():
    A += [x]
A = np.array(A)
```

Is there a better solution to this which operates on a numpy array from the start and avoids the creation of a standard python list?

Note that the += operator allows to extend an empty and dimensionless array with an arbitrarily dimensioned array whereas np.append and np.concatenate demand for equally dimensioned arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535374/initialize-a-numpy-array

Comment: no, my point is slightly different: image the case where you successively built up the array or you want to initialize each element differently. However, I really need the exactly same functionality, not only the same result.

Comment: why are you even doing a loop with this? why not just make `A = [[0,1],[1,2],[3,4]]` ?

Comment: another possible duplicate.. you really need to research what you are looking for first... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346336/list-of-lists-into-array-in-numpy

Comment: ok, sorry for the bad example. I will edit it again...

Comment: i just edited my query again.. maybe something like that? not sure what you are getting returned from your function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.fromiter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html):

```
def f(n):
    for j in range(n):
        yield j

>>> np.fromiter(f(5), dtype=np.intp)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

If you know beforehand the number of items the iterator is going to return, you can speed things up using the `count` keyword argument:

```
>>> np.fromiter(f(5), dtype=np.intp, count=5)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the same array `A`, do:

```
A = numpy.arange(5)
```

Arrays are not in general meant to be dynamically sized, but you could use `numpy.concatenate`.

Comment: I see your requirement has changed - what in general are you trying to achieve?

Comment: basically said, i will achieve the same functionality like I know it from the += operator in basic python lists for numpy arrays

Comment: @morph look into `np.hstack` and `np.vstack`