# How do I initialize a numpy array starting at a particular number?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I can initialize a numpy array and reshape it at the time of creation.

```
test = np.arange(32).reshape(4, 8)
```

which produces this:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
   [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
   [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
   [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]])
```

... but I'd like to know how to start the sequential numbering at a given point, say at 13 rather than at 0. How is that done in numpy?

I've looked for answers and found something [somewhat similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535374/initialize-a-numpy-array) but it seems there would be a numpy command to do this.

Comment: google np.arange..first hit - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Comment: Just add 13 to that array - `test += 13`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) takes an optional `start` argument.

```
start = 13 # Any number works here
np.arange(start, start + 32).reshape(4, 8)

# array([[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
#        [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
#        [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36],
#        [37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44]])
```