# Intializing three dimensional array in python with predefined values as -1

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

In c/c++ we use to declare three-dimensional using the following syntax.

```
`long long dp[20][180][2]; `
 memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((20,180,2))
```

How can we declare and initialize a three-dimensional array in python?

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [initialize a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535374/initialize-a-numpy-array)

Comment: initialize all value by -1

Comment: x = -np.ones(920,180,2))` or `x = np.zeros((20,180,2))-1` also do this.  Once you have an array, doing simple math on it is fast and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the values initialized to `-1` like in your `memset` example, then you'd want `np.full` instead of `np.zeros`

```
import numpy as np
x = np.full((20,180,2), -1)
```